# display.getSize(size) returns wrong screen size with Galaxy S10

Tags: java, android, screen

I use the following code to get the device screen size. This works on all my devices except Galaxy S10. Galaxy S10 has 3040 vertical pixels and this function returns something around 2800?

```java
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
```

Comment: I guess I need to explain my problem in more detail. I use .getSize method to get the "usable" screen size for my app. Based on this information I calculate specific touch points. This works fine except Galaxy S10. My app's screen starts below the "O" of the Infinity O display. Seems that .getSize calculates vertical screen size from that point. However, in reality the display starts above the "O" and therefore my calculation for the correct touch points is on the wrong position. At least this is what I think.

Comment: OK. I solved the problem. It was my fault. I made a mistake in the AndroidManifest.xml which caused this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The size returned by `getSize()` does not necessarily return actual size. Check the documentation for the reasons for this which I have quoted below from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize(android.graphics.Point)).

> 1. The returned size may be adjusted to exclude certain system decor elements that are always visible.
> 2. It may be scaled to provide compatibility with older applications that were originally designed for smaller displays.
> 3. It can be different depending on the WindowManager to which the display belongs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this:

```
public static int getDisplayHeight(Context context) {
    WindowManager windowManager =(WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
    return displayMetrics.heightPixels - getNavigationBarHeight(context);
}

public static int getNavigationBarHeight(Context context) {
    if (context != null && context.getResources() != null) {
      Resources resources = context.getResources();
      int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
      return resourceId > 0 ? resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId) : 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```